# Come si dice "to try" in italiano? Provare, cercare, o qualcos'altro?

Tags: translation

Google Translate dice che "to try" è "provare", ma credo che questo è "to try" come "I'd like to try the gelato". Vorrei capire come si dice "to try" come "I tried to hit the ball" o qualcosa simile. Sto leggendo un po', e in un libro, dice "Lui cercò di carpirgli la lettera." Sembra che questo uso sia il modo che sto cercando, ma non so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Cercare*  nel senso di *cerare di carpirgli la lettera* is to try:

**To try:**

> - cercare di + infinitive --> to try to do something (attempting to do something)
>
>   - Ho cercato di chiamare lo studio del dentista per prenotare una visita, ma mi rispondeva sempre la segreteria telefonica.
>       *I tried calling the dentist’s office to schedule an appointment, but I always got the voice mail.*
>   - Dovete cercare di cambiare macchina.
>       *You have to try to get a new car.*
>   - Cercava di non intromettersi nella conversazione, ma non era un tipo silenzioso.
>       *He tried not to intrude on the conversation, but he wasn’t the silent type.*

Sinonimi di *cercare* in questo senso sono: *provare e tentare*

The following **[link](http://www.newsinslowitalian.com/catalog/italian-grammar-online/55/special-verbs.html)** contains useful information on usage.